# how to access dynamically created uilabel in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created dynamic `UILabel` with tag value and i have similar kind of other labels without tag values.

Now i want access only tag values labels but i was not able to acces the label text value.

Here is my code.

```
 Dynamic created Label
     for (int i= 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        UILabel *defaultLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 70, 60, 21)];
        defaultLbl.text = @"Default";
        defaultLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        defaultLbl.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [defaultLbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12]];
        defaultLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        defaultLbl.tag = i+1;
        [myButton addSubview:defaultLbl];
        [defaultLbl release];

        UILabel *masterProName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 20, 200, 21)];
        masterProName.text = [masterProjListArray objectAtIndex:i];//@"Lorem Ipusum";
        masterProName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        masterProName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:153.0/255.0 blue:204.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        [masterProName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:17]];
        masterProName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        [myButton addSubview:masterProName];
        [masterProName release];

        UILabel *masterProID = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(28, 45, 200, 21)];
        masterProID.text = [masterProjIDArray objectAtIndex:i];//@"133 FS";
        masterProID.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        masterProID.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:51.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];;
        [masterProID setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17]];
        masterProID.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        [myButton addSubview:masterProID];
        [masterProID release];
    }
```

And `UILabel` access method after user press the long press button

```
- (void)longPressTap:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
         {
          if ([recognizer.view tag]) {
                        UILabel *view = (UILabel *)recognizer.view;
                    NSLog(@"---%@", view.subviews);

                    for (UILabel *lbl in view.subviews) {
                        if (recognizer.view.tag == view.tag) {
                            NSString *text = view.text;
                            NSLog(@"---%@", text);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
```

here am putting the log

```
"<UIImageView: 0x75b9510; frame = (0 0; 379 100); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x75acef0>>",
            "<UILabel: 0x88c4e50; frame = (28 20; 200 21); text = 'Aux Water Waste Trtmnt'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x88c49c0>>",
            "<UILabel: 0x88c52f0; frame = (28 45; 200 21); text = 'M10000'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x88c5380>>",
            "<UILabel: 0x88c56c0; frame = (30 70; 60 21); text = '**Default**'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x88c5750>>",
            "<UIButton: 0x88c6440; frame = (240 10; 70 80); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x88c6500>>"
```

In this log i want to access only "Default" text label

Please give me any suggestion on this.

Comment: You have two subviews with the tag 1. So what do you expect?

Comment: Hi temp, How did you resolve it. Now I have the same problem. Please let me know your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to know which value the tag has of the lable with "Default" in its text. Let's assume it is 42. Then

```
UILabel *label = [view viewWithTag:42];
```

would do the trick. 
Anyway your solution should work too. Have a look at the actual tag values that you are dealing with. i've got a guts feeling that recognizer.view.tag does not have the same value as the tag of the label with "Default" in it.

Comment: recognizer.view.tag have the same value as the tag of the label with "Default" in it.
here i had multiple subview labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create outlets of those at runtime.

Create an array, and go on to add outlets of each label.

Once you are done and need to retrieve them you can easily access by index of arrays.

Even you can create a dictionary for storing outlets, here you can access labels by keys.

Answer (score 0):

As you are assigning tag to `UILabel`, we can get label from tag (if it known to us, in your case we know).

So give it a try this way

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i <[array count]; i++)
    {
        UILabel *lbl = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:i+1];
        NSLog(@"--- %@", lbl.text);
    }
```

Comment: If it is having only one label we can access but i am having multiples UIlabels. so in this case how could i access

Comment: @temp you are assigning defaultLbl.tag = i+1; that means you know tags. Also you know array count and you have assigned tags with +1 of i So you can simply fetch values from tag.

Answer (score 0):

for get `UILabel` base on its `Tag`.

Take `int i;` in `.h file`,
And put `i=1;` in above **for Loop**

```
for (NSObject *view in self.View.subviews) 
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
    {
        label = (UILabel *)[[self view] viewWithTag:i];
        NSLof(@"%@".label.text);
       // break;
    }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should be checking

```
 if (lbl.tag == view.tag)
```

not

```
if (recognizer.view.tag == view.tag)
```

Secondly, it won't work anyway. All that does is identify the view that has been touched which you know. How about setting the tag value in the label you want to a unique number and testing

```
if (lbl.tag == <unique tag number>)
```